# Dealloc Being Called Twice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, memory-management

**Resloved!**

**Thanks to Lone Gunman, this issue was due to an oversight of not setting the many delegates to nil before releasing them.**

This is a strange one...  I'm familiar with basic memory management but I think something is unusual about what I am seeing.  Here is a little background...

I have a NavigationController that handles the navigation between the following ViewControllers:

Home -> Games -> Game

When running the code it falls down when leaving the Game.  Within the GameViewController there is a dealloc method that resembles:

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [board release];
    [opponentsViewController release];
    [instructionsViewController release];
    [imgPicker release];
    [gameView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When the navigation controller goes back to the Games list (from the Game) it throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  So I bring up my trusty profiler and check for Zombies.  Alas, just as I expected a message is being sent to a deallocated object!  Digging deeper I find there to be 3 entries in the object's history:

1. Board getting alloc'd (called by Game's init method)
2. Board getting released (called by Game's dealloc method)
3. Board being Zombie'd (called by Game's dealloc method)

Both calls 2 and 3 are called from UINavigationController setDisappearingViewController.

In my dealloc method I set breakpoints to each release call, when doing so - the [board release] call occurs, then the [opponentsViewController release] call occurs then the [board release] call occurs again.  So I'm seeing the dealloc method does not finish completely and calls again.

What might be causing this?

Edit: This is the [GameViewController Implementation](https://gist.github.com/84f1e1026d4201fa6bc1)

Code from the Games controller that adds this game:

```
-(void) gotoGame:(int)tag {

    game = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:game animated:YES];
    [game release];

}
```

Edit: This is the [GameViewController Header](https://gist.github.com/32a13d2b1a95fe0f7ee5)

Comment: `-[NSObject dealloc]` cannot be executed twice. If you enable 'Run Static Analyser' in the build settings and try to build again, what issues do you get?

Comment: This happens when you are calling release too many times. Can you check you are not releasing Board anywhere else in the program WITHOUT retaining it?>

Comment: @ WTP: No complaints from the static analyzer.

Comment: How many times do you release and retain board?

Comment: Edit: Added implementation file for GameViewController

Comment: If Lone Gunman answered the question, you should mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try setting all your ivar's delegates to nil (EDIT: in dealloc).  I've had a similar problem with a fetched results controller.  Failed to set the its delegate to nil in dealloc and the core data stack still had a pointer to it when the view controller was released.

So that's my bet, set ivar delegates to nil in dealloc, although I can't see your header to know what protocols your are conforming to be sure.

EDIT: Explanation

Setting a delegate is actually giving the object that is doing the delegation a pointer (I believe it usually an assigned property).

```
@property (assign) delegate;
```

I'll use the problem I had as an example.

So let's say you have a view controller that has a fetchedResultsController as an ivar.  When you set the FRCs delegate:

```
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

and the view controller gets released, any object that is using that pointer still thinks it's live.  You would think since the FRC is getting released in dealloc as well, you'd be fine(which is why it took me 4 days to figure this out :) ), but sometimes other parts of an implementation use your delegate as well.  So the fix is:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    [_fetchedResultsController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note: as soon as the new tools are available to everyone you won't have to worry about this stuff anymore ^ ^;

Comment: Thats a really good point.  Here is the header, there are a BUNCH of delegates in this...  I would imagine this is the right direction.

Comment: Fixed, thank you!  I'm hoping somebody can help fill in a gap in my knowledge.  What are the delegates doing to make it seem like dealloc is firing twice?  Are the [super dealloc] calls in their methods cause this to fire again?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: You are a genius. Saved me. What's interesting is iOS 5 did not have this issue, but when I tested on iOS 4.3 it started crashing on dealloc.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
- (void) dealloc {
    if(game != nil){
     //release here
     [game release];
    }
    [super dealloc];
  }
```

By the way it seems you have declare game in header file and just after pushing you are releasing it and also in dealloc method you are releasing it. Either remove the release call from dealloc method or change you method like this.

```
-(void) gotoGame:(int)tag {

    GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:game animated:YES];
    [game release];

}
```

**UPDATE**

Also you are not using the tag anywhere. Why don't you create your init method like this

```
GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithTag:tag];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:game animated:YES];
[game release];
```

Comment: Checking wether something is nil before sending it release (or any other method) is useless. Calling a method on nil is a noop. It does nothing. Hence your suggestion won't fix anything either.

Comment: @Johan Kool atleast his app won't crash.

Comment: You miss the point. Sending a `-release` message to `nil` will **not** crash his app. Moreover, an object does not become `nil`  automatically after it has become deallocated (or, in other words, `nil` does not denote garbage values). So the check is useless. (One thing commonly done in `-dealloc` implementations is to zero out the pointer, which can prevent crashes, but it can also hide bugs).

Comment: Rahul, you absolutely don't know (or ignore) the basic memory management rules, by suggesting the if+release thing, moreover you don't know (or ignore) the fact the messages can be sent to nil ...