# dealloc called twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dealloc

I have this case where i want to pop from a view and go back to the original view.
After the button is pressed the app crashes, and the console displays EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I run it in instruments with zombies enabled and this is what i get: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APbkg.png)
[image: dealloc called twice]

as it is shown the dealloc is called twice for the same object. 
instruments are pointing to an `NSMutableArray`which contains `NSStrings`.

can anyone help me solve this issue...
thank you.

ps: the solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6485023/690917) does not solve the issue.

Edit:
the array is filled with data parsed from an xml file.

```
-(void) grabData{
    listOfNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSString *XMLPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"chi.xml"];
    NSData *XMLData   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:XMLPath];
    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:XMLData options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

    NSArray *items = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"/template/item" error:nil];
    for (CXMLElement *node in items) {
        int counter;
        if([[[node attributeForName:@"type"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"label"]){
            for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
                [listOfNames addObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]];
            }
        }
...
```

and is used in this function:

```
-(void)setupPage{
    [scroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scroll.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scroll.clipsToBounds=YES;
    scroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroll.pagingEnabled=NO;
    int y=Y;
    CGFloat cy=0;
    int count=[listOfProperties count];
    int total=count;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        NSString *class=[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[(NSObject *)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i] class]] autorelease];
        if([class isEqualToString:@"textFieldCell"]){
            ((textFieldCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).str=[listOfNames objectAtIndex:i];
            [((textFieldCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]) setTarget:scroll];
            ((textFieldCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).view.frame=CGRectMake(X,y,self.view.frame.size.width - remProfX,cellProfH);
            [((textFieldCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]) setImage:[self getImageName:i maxValue:(count-1)]];
            [scroll addSubview:((textFieldCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).view];
        }
        else{
            if([class isEqualToString:@"comboBoxCell"]){
                ((comboBoxCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).str=[listOfNames objectAtIndex:i];
                [((comboBoxCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]) setTarget:self.view];
                ((comboBoxCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).view.frame=CGRectMake(X,y,self.view.frame.size.width - remProfX,cellProfH);
                [((comboBoxCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]) setImage:[self getImageName:i maxValue:(count-1)]];
                [scroll addSubview:((comboBoxCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).view];
            }
            else{
                if([class isEqualToString:@"dateCell"]){
                    ((dateCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).str=[listOfNames objectAtIndex:i];
                    [((dateCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]) setTarget:self.view];
                    ((dateCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).view.frame=CGRectMake(X,y,self.view.frame.size.width - remProfX,cellProfH);
                    [((dateCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]) setImage:[self getImageName:i maxValue:(count-1)]];
                    [scroll addSubview:((dateCell*)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i]).view];
                }
            }
...
```

dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [listOfNames release];
    [listOfProperties release];
    [listOfGroupNames release];
    [listOfCheckBoxNames release];
    [listOfCheckBoxes release];
    [listOfButtons release];
    [scroll release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code surrounding the array?

Comment: Add the code where you create and release the array. specially the dealloc method.

Comment: @Cyprian the array is created in the beginning if the grabData function. i added the dealloc code.

Comment: Have you searched through all of your code to find if you have any 'release's on the object other than where there should be?

Comment: Is the array a `@property`? Because if it is, and is not instantiated properly, it's possible that the array is getting released elsewhere.

Comment: @Nick Bull double checked that.

Comment: @Patrick Perini @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfNames;

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your dealloc and see which line it faults on, then you'll know which item you are double releasing

Comment: @Nick Bull: instruments are pointing to `listOfNames`. but ill check it...

Comment: Does the @property for str in textFieldCell retain the string?

Comment: @Daniel yes it is retained in textFieldCell, comboBoxCell and dateCell...

Comment: Without the entire coude I don't think we will be able to find your problem, sometimes it's not where the instrument is pointing as at first site.

Comment: if someone is interested ill gladly upload the project somewhere...

Comment: @Nagi not the entire project code, but the entire class code both .h and .m files are almost always helpful with tracking this kind of problems.

Comment: Check where mainViewProfile2 is created and released as well.

Comment: ok i think i got the problem... `scroll` was being released in `textFieldCell`. that is why is was being called twice! now i have a warning that comes from my `dateCell` class. it says `modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x4b664d0`. it doesn't crash the app... any idea? thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

This might have happened if you created your NSArray as an autoreleased object using one of those methods:

```
+ array
+ arrayWithArray:
+ arrayWithContentsOfFile:
+ arrayWithContentsOfURL:
+ arrayWithObject:
+ arrayWithObjects:
+ arrayWithObjects:count:
```

And then in the dealloc method of your closing UIViewController you are releasing this array.

**EDIT**
By the way class word is reseverd it's bad to use it like you did here:

```
NSString *class=[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[(NSObject *)[listOfProperties objectAtIndex:i] class]] autorelease];
```

Comment: The word `class` isn't reserved, it's just the name of a method. You're right that it's not a great idea to use it, though.